# Get New CustomerID using Self Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, adventureworks

I am trying to get all customerID who didn't place an order in the previous year. My logic to solve this is to do a self left john like below.

```
SELECT distinct t1.[CustomerID]
FROM [AdventureWorks2008].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] t1
    LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2008].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] t2
    on t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
Where 
    t1.OrderDate >= '20040101'
    and t2.OrderDate > '20030101'
    and t2.OrderDate <= '20031231'
    and t2.customerID is null
```

But it returns an empty set.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: When you use a table you left joined to in where condition, you are effectively turning that left join into inner. Move the t2.OrderDate conditions from WHERE to JOIN like in Tim Biegeleisen's answer or use EXISTS like in fen1x's answer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `WHERE` conditions to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT distinct t1.[CustomerID]
FROM [AdventureWorks2008].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] t1
LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2008].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] t2
   ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID AND
      t1.OrderDate >= '20040101'    AND
      t2.OrderDate BETWEEN '20030101' AND '20031231'
WHERE t2.customerID IS NULL
```

Your original query was a bit paradoxical because matching records from the previous year would never be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `not exists`:

```
SELECT distinct t1.[CustomerID]
FROM [AdventureWorks2008].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] t1
WHERE not exists (
        select 1
        from [AdventureWorks2008].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] t2
        where t1.customerID = t2.customerID
            and t2.OrderDate > '20030101'
            and t2.OrderDate <= '20031231'
    )
```

Comment: and `AND t1.OrderDate >= '20040101'` in outer WHERE

Answer (score 0):

We have little information to solve your query problem.

Can you give us your tables description?

The only possible problem I the where clause:

```
Where 
    t1.OrderDate >= '20040101'
    and t2.OrderDate > '20030101'
    and t2.OrderDate <= '20031231'
    and t2.customerID is null
```

I suppose OrderDate interval should be the same from both cursors, isn't it? 
Try it with this where clause:

```
Where 
    t1.OrderDate >= '20030101'
    and t2.OrderDate > '20030101'
    and t2.OrderDate <= '20031231'
    and t2.customerID is null
```